# Deploy MS-Access plugin without adding registry entries?

Tags: c#, ms-access, vba

A customer asked me today if it was possible to deploy an access-plugin without adding or changing registry entries.

The customer is forced to have his terminalservers managed by a third party. This third party has very strong objections against any changes in the registry.

I know in MS Excel you can easily define a directoy from which any file will be loaded when Excel starts. We already use this feature to enhance our customers Excel. Now we would like to add some functionality to Access in a similar way.

Any help (even a plain "there is no way without editing the registry") is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
sam

*edit:*

Maybe I should point out our "plugin" would be very small. It's function would be to provide a very simple GUI, firing a few http-requests against our webservice and maybe adding some kind of metadata to the access-db.

Since I'm no expert in MS-Office-Development it might be totally possible I don't even need a plugin. Maybe Access offers something weaker which would suffice?

Comment: It is as reasonable to object to the tide coming in as it is to object to changes to the registry - both are inevitable unless you want to do something as drastic as destroying the sun and the moon...

Answer (score 2):

Registry settings are required: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.100).aspx.

Your customer needs to tell his terminal server managers to get over themselves.

If the terminal server managers are working for your customer, then they have to do what your customer wants, even if they don't like the way he wants to do things.  If they still won't cooperate, find a new hosting company.

If your customer is an employee of the TS managers (or they are both employees in the same organization), he needs to tell them that they are being unreasonable, that registry changes are as inevitable and natural as the tides and the rising and setting of the sun and moon (Most software of any complexity changes the registry on installation and often whenever it is run), and any attempt to prevent registry changes will eventually lead to disaster or continual breaches of policy.

On the other hand, the terminal server managers may be objecting to *manual* changes in the registry.  In that case, if the add-in/plug-in has its own installer which makes the required registry settings, they can examine the installer to make sure it isn't making any unreasonable changes to the registry.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.
Sadly I can not force my customer to change his hosting company. Also, he would not want to.

It's not like the hosting company would not add registry entries under any circumstances. But the process for this is a pain in the a....

I will edit my question to make it more clear. Maybe I'm mistaken and I don't even need a plugin.